# How to sync my contacts to Openfire using Smack? Or how to know which contact(from my contactlist) is registered on openfire?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm working on a chat app, and on initial stage of the chatting phase. I come to the point where i want to filter my contacts in two parts like Registered users and Unregistered users.like whatsapp and telegram does.In my app users can register themselves by Phone number.
Should i compare all registered users from my contact-list?
if yes than
Is it good way to compare? if there are thousands of registered users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `User Search` plugin to check if a User is registered on openfire or not.